# Cannot understand how does XSS attack damage

Tags: security, owasp

I cannot understand what damage does an XSS attack do. When I add to input, e.g onmouse() function and it display an image, this image will not appear for another user, but for me and will disappear after refreshing. how can we save it on the server via html?

Answer (score 0):

XSS attacks work by exploiting vulnerabilities in a website code.

To take a trivial example:

Given an input which prompts the user to enter their name and then responds with "Hello, YOUR NAME". If the site just echos back what was input unchanged (i.e. without XSS protection) then someone could type `<script> ... </script>` and run some JavaScript on the site.

If that's the case then an attacker could write a form on *their* site but set the `action` to that page. They could then have a hidden input containing some JavaScript. Then they could submit the form with JS.

Now, if the attacker tricked the victim into visiting the attacker's site, the form would be submitted to the original site by the victim's browser and the JS would run in their browser.

The JS could then do something bad such as copying data out of their cookies and sending it to the attacker. The attacker could then inject that cookie into their browser and use the original site while logged in as the victim.

Now imagine if the original site was your online banking or webmail. All your personal data would be available to the attacker.

---

That example is of a **reflected** XSS attack.

The other kind of attack is a **stored** XSS attack.

---

Take, for example, a forum. It allows you to post messages. These are saved to a database and displayed to all the visitors.

Now if the data stored in the database was echoed back without XSS protection then the JS would run for *everyone* visiting the site.

---

So in short:

> how can we save it on the server via html?

You can't use HTML to do this.

You need to send an HTTP request (stored) or cause the victim to do so (stored or reflected) which exploits a flaw in the site's code.